# I'm trying to create a microservice for my grpc

Tags: android, spring-boot, grpc

I'm trying to create a microservice for my grpc I'm using the "io.grpc" library I create the server and call the client on my android it works fine but I used to use rest api with microservice there is something native to create microservice in grpc for spring boot without using http methods?

I'm grateful for any help